# Spark Scala to count length in dataframe fields

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, user-defined-functions

New to Scala.

I have created a substring function in scala which requires "pos" and "len", I want pos to be hardcoded, however for the length it should count it from the dataframe. How would I go about doing this?

Here is my code:

```
val A = DF.select(col("example_ref"), substring(col("example_ref"),11, 21))
```

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

So added this code:

```
val A = DF.select($"example_ref",substring($"example_ref",11,length($"example_ref")))
```

However I get the following errors:

```
Type Mismatch, expected: String, actual: Column
Type Mismatch, expected: Int, actual: Column
```

Comment: What do you mean by "count it from the dataframe"? You want to get the length of the `example_ref` column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an UDF to get the length of a column and then encapsulate the substring function in an expr function

```
val colLength = udf { (col: String) => col.size }
```

And then use it in your code

```
val A = DF.select(col("example_ref"), expr("substring(col(example_ref),11, colLength(col(example_ref)))"))
```

PS. I like most the dollar syntax to get the columns

```
val A = DF.select($"example_ref", expr("substring(example_ref,11, colLength(example_ref))"))
```

**EDIT**

As pointed out in comments there is already a function to do that so you don't even need to define the UDF:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.length
val A = DF.select($"example_ref", expr("substring(example_ref,11, length(example_ref))"))
```

**QUICK EXAMPLE**

**INPUT**

```
scala> val df = sc.parallelize(List((1, "abc"),(2, "bcd"),(3, "cde"))).toDF("number", "mycolumn")
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [number: int, mycolumn: string]

scala> df.show
+------+--------+
|number|mycolumn|
+------+--------+
|     1|     abc|
|     2|     bcd|
|     3|     cde|
+------+--------+
```

**OUTPUT**

```
df.select(expr("substring(mycolumn, 2, length(mycolumn))")).show
+----------------------------------------+
|substring(mycolumn, 2, length(mycolumn))|
+----------------------------------------+
|                                      bc|
|                                      cd|
|                                      de|
+----------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Or just use `org.apache.spark.sql.functions.length`.

Comment: Thank you guys, appreciate your help,

Comment: Why is the dollar syntax better to use?

Comment: Hey, just tried the code and I get an error, it says: Type Mismatch expected: String actual: column

Comment: post your function so we can check it properly

Comment: I'll edit my answer, you can do it using expr. I'ts working for me. Hope it's valid for you as well

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, really appreciate it! it worked for me when I replaced '$' with col.